# php - how to point internal array pointer to specific element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associated array who's last elements start with

```
[0] => value
```

moving onwards

```
[1] => value, [2] => value ... etc
```

But it wont be determined until run time how many elements there will be (1, 2 ,3 etc). So, I am trying to write a script which will pull off those last elements and store them in a separate array for looping. To do this, I will need to know how to point start the pointer at associated array element [0] and then continue until the end of the array.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have tried something?

Comment: Would you please provide more information? I'm not sure I understand what you want. Also note that arrays have indexes rather than pointers.

Comment: confused as to what you are asking but array_slice() sounds like a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
$array = array("1","2","3","value","more","stuff","here");
if ($foundit = array_search("value",$array)) {
  $new_array = array_slice($array,$foundit);
}
print_r($new_array);
Array
(
[0] => value
[1] => more
[2] => stuff
[3] => here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have control over the code that dynamically generates the elements that need to be added to your array. If this is the case, you can use PHP's array_push() function to append to the end of the existing array.

[PHP Manual: array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no pointers, but if you need to iterate over whole array (no matter associative it or not) you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

like

```
foreach($array ask $key => $value)
    echo $key . ' ' . $value;
```